# Getting error when I trying to test my contract

Tags: solidity, javascript, hardhat

I started coding project and I got error when trying to test him.
When I trying to call some contract function from js tester i got error:

```
Error: call revert exception [ See: https://links.ethers.org/v5-errors-CALL_EXCEPTION ] (method="getEntranceFee()", data="0x", errorArgs=null, errorName=null, errorSignature=null, reason=null, code=CALL_EXCEPTION, version=abi/5.7.0)
      at Logger.makeError (node_modules\@ethersproject\logger\src.ts\index.ts:269:28)
      at Logger.throwError (node_modules\@ethersproject\logger\src.ts\index.ts:281:20)
      at Interface.decodeFunctionResult (node_modules\@ethersproject\abi\src.ts\interface.ts:427:23)
      at Contract.<anonymous> (node_modules\@ethersproject\contracts\src.ts\index.ts:400:44)
      at step (node_modules\@ethersproject\contracts\lib\index.js:48:23)
      at Object.next (node_modules\@ethersproject\contracts\lib\index.js:29:53)
      at fulfilled (node_modules\@ethersproject\contracts\lib\index.js:20:58)
      at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
      at runNextTicks (node:internal/process/task_queues:64:3)
      at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:540:9)
```

Here is my codes:

```
!developmentChains.includes(network.name) ? describe.skip : describe("Lottery Unit Test", () => {
    let lottery, vrfCoordinatorV2Mock, lotteryEntranceFee, deployer, interval;
    const chainId = network.config.chainId;

    beforeEach(async () => { // before all testing we do this part of code (get our contracts)
        deployer = (await getNamedAccounts()).deployer;
        await deployments.fixture(["all"]); // means that we want deploy everything
        lottery = await ethers.getContractAt("Lottery", deployer);
        vrfCoordinatorV2Mock = await ethers.getContractAt("VRFCoordinatorV2Mock", deployer);
        lotteryEntranceFee = await lottery.getEntranceFee(); // here I got error
        interval = await lottery.getInterval(); // and here I got error
    })
})
```

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.19;

import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/interfaces/VRFCoordinatorV2Interface.sol";
import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/VRFConsumerBaseV2.sol";
import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/interfaces/KeeperCompatibleInterface.sol";
import "hardhat/console.sol";

/* using error instead of require is gas efficient */
error Lottery__NotEnoughFund();
error Lottery__TransferFailed();
error Lottery__LotteryIsClosed();
error Lottery__UpkeepNotNeeded(
    uint256 curBalance,
    uint256 numPlayers,
    uint256 lotteryState
);

/**
 * @title A sample Lottery contract
 * @author me
 * @notice This contract is for creation untamperable decentralized smart contract
 * @dev This contract is using Chainlink VRF v2 and Chainlink Keepers
 */

contract Lottery is VRFConsumerBaseV2, KeeperCompatibleInterface {
    // here: 0 - OPEN, 1 - PENDING and etc.
    enum LotteryState {
        OPEN,
        PENDING
    }

    uint256 private constant ENTRANCE_FEE = 0.01 ether;
    uint8 private constant REQUEST_CONFIRMATION = 3;
    uint8 private constant NUM_WORD = 1; // we need only one random number

    address payable[] private s_players; // if somebody from players array wins we should pay them and its why we put here 'payable'
    address private s_winner;

    VRFCoordinatorV2Interface private immutable i_vrfCoordinator;

    bytes32 private immutable i_gasLane;
    uint64 private immutable i_subId;
    uint32 private immutable i_callbackGasLimit;
    uint256 private immutable i_interval;

    uint256 private s_lastTimeStamp;

    LotteryState private s_lotteryState;

    /*'event' use for getting some info from blockchain when in blockchain something happens (winning in lottery like example) */
    event LotteryEnter(address indexed player); // 'indexed' means that value will be easier to read
    event RequestedLotteryWinner(uint256 indexed requestId);
    event PickedWinner(address indexed winner);

    constructor(
        address vrfCoordinatorV2, // contract
        bytes32 gasLane, // keyHash
        uint64 subscriptionId,
        uint32 callbackGasLimit,
        uint256 interval
    ) VRFConsumerBaseV2(vrfCoordinatorV2) {
        i_vrfCoordinator = VRFCoordinatorV2Interface(vrfCoordinatorV2);
        i_gasLane = gasLane;
        i_subId = subscriptionId;
        i_callbackGasLimit = callbackGasLimit;
        s_lotteryState = LotteryState.OPEN; // checker if lottery is open or closed
        s_lastTimeStamp = block.timestamp;
        i_interval = interval;
    }

    function enterLottery() public payable {
        if (msg.value < ENTRANCE_FEE) {
            revert Lottery__NotEnoughFund(); // instead a require to be gas efficient
        }
        if (s_lotteryState != LotteryState.OPEN) {
            revert Lottery__LotteryIsClosed();
        }
        s_players.push(payable(msg.sender));
        emit LotteryEnter(msg.sender);
    }

    /**
     * @dev This is the function that the Chainlink Keeper nodes call
     * they look for `upkeepNeeded` to return True.
     * the following should be true for this to return true:
     * 1. The time interval has passed between raffle runs.
     * 2. The lottery is open.
     * 3. The contract has ETH.
     * 4. Implicity, your subscription is funded with LINK.
     */

    function checkUpkeep(
        bytes memory /* checkData */ // also function don't use it but needed
    )
        public
        view
        override
        returns (
            bool upkeepNeeded,
            bytes memory /* performData */ // use if we want that 'checkUpkeep' doing some other stuff
        )
    {
        bool isOpen = (s_lotteryState == LotteryState.OPEN);
        bool timePassed = ((block.timestamp - s_lastTimeStamp) > i_interval);
        bool hasPlayers = (s_players.length > 0);
        bool hasBalance = (address(this).balance > 0);

        upkeepNeeded = (isOpen && timePassed && hasPlayers && hasBalance); // check all indicators
    }

    function performUpkeep(bytes calldata /* performData */) external override {
        (bool upkeepNeeded, ) = checkUpkeep("");
        if (!upkeepNeeded) {
            revert Lottery__UpkeepNotNeeded(
                address(this).balance,
                s_players.length,
                uint256(s_lotteryState)
            );
        }

        s_lotteryState = LotteryState.PENDING; // while we pick a random winner we put our state pending

        /* this is also call event like emit */
        uint256 requestId = i_vrfCoordinator.requestRandomWords(
            i_gasLane, // maximum size of gas for number
            i_subId, // Id that this contract uses for funding requests
            REQUEST_CONFIRMATION, // how many confirmations we should wait to get result (recommend min. 2)
            i_callbackGasLimit, // limit how much gas uses to callback requests
            NUM_WORD // how much numbers we get
        );

        /* this is redundant event because in the top requestId also call event */
        emit RequestedLotteryWinner(requestId);
    }

    function fulfillRandomWords(
        uint256 /* requestId */, // we make 'requestId' unused instead of delete because we didn't use this value but out function are needed this
        uint256[] memory randomWords
    ) internal override {
        uint256 indexOfWinner = randomWords[0] % s_players.length;
        address payable winner = s_players[indexOfWinner];
        s_winner = winner;
        s_players = new address payable[](0);
        s_lastTimeStamp = block.timestamp;
        (bool success, ) = winner.call{value: address(this).balance}(""); // we tranfer all money to address of winner
        if (!success) {
            revert Lottery__TransferFailed();
        }

        s_lotteryState = LotteryState.OPEN;
        emit PickedWinner(winner);
    }

    function getInterval() public view returns (uint256) {
        return i_interval;
    }

    function getEntranceFee() public pure returns (uint256) {
        return ENTRANCE_FEE;
    }

    function getPlayer(uint256 index) public view returns (address) {
        return s_players[index];
    }

    function getWinner() public view returns (address) {
        return s_winner;
    }

    function getLotteryState() public view returns (LotteryState) {
        return s_lotteryState;
    }

    function getNumWords() public pure returns (uint256) {
        // function 'pure' instead of 'view' because we return constant variable
        return NUM_WORD;
    }

    function getNumberOfPlayers() public view returns (uint256) {
        return s_players.length;
    }

    function getLatestTimeStamp() public view returns (uint256) {
        return s_lastTimeStamp;
    }

    function getRequestConfirmation() public pure returns (uint256) {
        return REQUEST_CONFIRMATION;
    }
}
```

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **(CALL_EXCEPTION)** error occurs when your smart contract is not deployed yet.

**So you should wait for the deployment transaction to pass before accessing the contract's methods.**

**It looks like your attempt to deploy all smart contracts at once may have adverse effects.**

You can't just simply call `deployments.fixture(['all'])` without setting up the deployment scripts in advance.

I haven't seen your deployment scripts, but if you do have them set up, make sure you added the tag at the end of the contract deployment script files.

Like the following:

```js
module.exports.tag = ["all", "Lottery"]
```

---

Otherwise, `deployments.fixture(['all'])` will not work, and you'll only be able to work it around by deploying the `Lottery` contract *explicitly* and ***inline***, like this:

```js
const lottery = await ethers.deployContract("Lottery", [...whatever arguments are required based on your current deployment script], {});

await lottery.waitForDeployment(); // IMPORTANT!
```